# How to select multiple messages in Gmail with keyboard?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Shift</kbd> key does not seem to be working with arrow keys or <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>.

<kbd>x</kbd> can be used to select multiple messages, but one has to hit <kbd>x</kbd> as many times as messages selected.

Looking for some elegant solution.

Answer (score 7):

Arrow key navigation in Gmail has been changed. Now you can use arrow key or <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> without using <kbd>shift</kbd>. First you need to **enable keyboard shortcut** feature. For that open your Gmail, press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> for a list of keyboard shortcuts. In case if you have not enabled already, you will see *'The following keyboard shortcuts are currently disabled'* just enable this and close the window.

Now scrolling up and down is simply done with the arrow up and down keys (<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> also will do same thing with and without using <kbd>shift</kbd> key).

Selecting or deselecting a message is <kbd>x</kbd>.

Select all conversations : <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Deselect all conversations : <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

Select read conversations : <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

Select unread conversations : <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>

Select starred conversations : <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

Select unstarred conversations : <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Comment: But how do I select multiple message at one time (without hitting x as many time as may messages to be selected)

Comment: @SandeepJindal: You didn't see the keyboard shortcuts carefully (press `shift`+`?`). All options given there. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @serenesat This does not answer the question.  The OP asked how to select multiple messages, not all of them.  Therefore the more recent posters appear to be correct, that this is not possible just with the keyboard in Gmail.  Which is a shame.

Answer (score 6):

> None of the existing answers answer the question. Imagine scrolling
>   through your email with arrow keys and pressing a key continuously
>   (unlike x) to select messages and not pressing it when you don't want
>   to select a message. Shift generally does it in most interfaces.

In Gmail, it is **not** possible to select **multiple chunks** of emails and mark checkboxes of those all multiple selected chunks at once. The only way is to select and mark emails one by one or select only a one chunk per time.

- **one by one selection:**

  - **<kbd>`ARROW UP`</kbd>** **<kbd>`ARROW DOWN`</kbd>** or **<kbd>`J`</kbd>** **<kbd>`K`</kbd>** for navigation
  - **<kbd>`X`</kbd>** for checkbox mark
- **chunk selection:**

  - mark the first checkbox of a chunk
  - press and hold **<kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd>** key
  - mark the last checkbox of a chunk (**with the mouse**)

Answer (score 4):

In order to select multiple messgase at once:

1. Place a check next to the first email in the range.
2. Hold 'Shift' and place a check next to the last email in the range.

Source: http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et022005.htm

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest answer would be that it's currently not possible with native Gmail keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

it is working for selection mail one by one(x key)